# make a proxy with two servers

Tags: ssh, proxy, webserver

I want to implement a proxy which has two (A and B) servers in the middle. traffic goes from my computer to server B and then to server A and then gets the data.
I found that with this configuration in ~/.ssh/config:

```
HOST B
    HostName B
    user debian
    DynamicForward 0.0.0.0:1081
```

I can use my 1081 port as a proxy. But now I don't know how to proxy all B's traffic through A.

This is my ssh version:

> OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016

Comment: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

B is just handling everything it gets to A. A must choose where to retrieve data depending on its data. Clearly only A should have the [*DynamicForward*](https://manpages.debian.org/ssh_config.5#DynamicForward) tunnel, the role of B is just an intermediate host for connectivity. Normally B should only require a classic [*LocalForward*](https://manpages.debian.org/ssh_config.5#LocalForward) to present queries to A.

This could be done in different ways, but the most simple and secure method takes advantage of the [*ProxyJump*](https://manpages.debian.org/ssh_config.5#ProxyJump) feature which will show A as if it was directly reachable, thus not requiring anymore to ponder how B will interact with the intended port forwarding. One can consider B is almost invisible. So in the end, the configuration below can be put in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host B
    User userb

Host A
    User usera
    ProxyJump B
    DynamicForward 1081
```

Invoked with only:

```
ssh A
```

Without configuration file the equivalent command line would be:

```
ssh -D 1081 -J userb@B usera@A
```

**UPDATE**: should *ssh*'s version be older than 7.3 (as it appears to be for OP), *ProxyJump* can still be replaced by [*ProxyCommand*](https://manpages.debian.org/ssh_config.5#ProxyCommand) + *ssh -W* like this:

as configuration file `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host B
    User userb

Host A
    User usera
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p B
    DynamicForward 1081
```

or without configuration file the equivalent command line:

```
ssh -D 1081 -o 'ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p userb@B' usera@A
```

The SOCKS5 API will be available on the client as `localhost:1081` (unless putting back `0.0.0.0:1081` (or using [*GatewayPorts*/*-g*](https://manpages.debian.org/ssh_config.5#GatewayPorts)) to make it available for other clients). Under the hood, handled by a pair of pipes, a spawned sub *ssh* process will establish a tunnel through Host B and will present A's ssh server to the initial *ssh* command: the whole ssh is tunneled that's why there's no specific additional port forwarding to be configured.

Comment: The first block of code should be written in ~/.ssh/config in my machine?

Comment: I get this error: ~/.ssh/config: line 14: Bad configuration option: proxyjump

Comment: and for second solution I get "unknown option -- J"

Comment: that means that your ssh is too old for the -J option. Can you tell what's your version with `ssh -V`? There are work-arounds.

Comment: Thanks it worked

Comment: Do you know any mobile client which I can do this on it?

Comment: Not really. That's an other topic entirely. Nothing will guarantee that installing an ssh client on the mobile phone (just look for them, it's easy to find) will be allowed by the smartphone's OS to open a listening socket. You should try this site: https://android.stackexchange.com/